# Angular Universal - different URL classes in server and client

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal application and I want to reuse code in server and client. Problem is I cannot seem to use the `URL` class to work properly in both environments.

In my code, I have a line like the following -

```
return new URL(this._productUrl);
```

When I have it this way, I get Exception printed in my Express server console -

> ERROR { ReferenceError: URL is not defined

To fix this, I added Node URL import like -

```
import { URL } from "url";
```

But, if I do this, I get error in JS console in client side -

> TypeError: url__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.URL is not a constructor

Not sure how to use the WHATWG URL in both client and server environment. Any help / pointer is appreciated.

Comment: As I understand, you are using URL node object: "https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_url" It works on server side, right, because it's a nodejs native object. But in the front, angular app, you have not those native nodejs objects. I'm right at the moment?. Are you trying to import in the front app the 'url' nodejs object?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to have same code run in both server and client side.

Comment: The problem is that URL as "constructor" it's not part of "standard" in front-end, for example for webworkers, and it's part of a draft at this moment you have: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL
But you can not use the same "new URL" in the backend and in the frontend, maybe, for angular there is a package, i'm going to perform a search, but talking only about the "standard" you can't use that line in both sides

Comment: You have this package for frontend: https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parse
This is the expose of the url interface of node, maybe you can use it

Comment: Yeah, as of now I am using a library similar to that.